# How can I get Excel sheet dropdown multiple values from Excel to php array?

Tags: phpexcel

I want to get Excel sheet dropdown multiple values , but when I try to get that value only first or selected default values are returned ..

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try.

Comment: How are you trying to get that value? Show code!